# Haskell: put in State monad seems to be elided

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I'm writing a program to allocate pizzas to people; each person will get one pizza, ideally of their favorite type, unless stock has run out, in which case they are given their next favorite type recursively.

My approach is to compute a `((User, Pizza), Int)` for the amount a person would like said pizza, sort those, and recurse through using a state monad to keep inventory counts.

The program is written and type checks:

```
allocatePizzasImpl :: [((User, Pizza), Int)] 
                   -> State [(Pizza, Int)] [(User, Pizza)]
allocatePizzasImpl [] = return []
allocatePizzasImpl ((user, (flavor, _)):ranks) =
    do inventory <- get
       -- this line is never hit
       put $ updateWith inventory (\i -> if i <= 0
                                         then Nothing
                                         else Just $ i - 1) flavor
       next <- allocatePizzasImpl $ filter ((/= user) . fst) ranks
       return $ (user, flavor) : next
```

and I have a helper function to extract the result:

```
allocatePizzas :: [Pizza] 
               -> [((User, Pizza), Int)] 
               -> [(User, Pizza)]
allocatePizzas pizzas rank = fst 
                           . runState (allocatePizzasImpl rank) 
                           $ buildQuotas pizzas
```

but the line indicated by `-- this line is never hit` is... never hit by any GHCI breakpoints; furthermore, if I break on the return call, GHCI says `inventory` isn't in scope.

When run, the result is assigning the same pizza (with one inventory count) to all users. Something is going wrong, but I have absolutely no idea how to proceed. I'm new to Haskell, so any comments on style would be appreciated as well =)

Thanks!

PS: For completeness, `updateWith` is defined as:

```
updateWith :: (Eq a, Eq b) 
           => [(a, b)]        -- inventory
           -> (b -> Maybe b)  -- update function; Nothing removes it
           -> a               -- key to update
           -> [(a, b)]
updateWith set update key =
    case lookup key set of
      Just b -> replace set
                        (unwrapPair (key, update b))
                        (fromMaybe 0 $ elemIndex (key, b) set)
      Nothing -> set
  where replace :: [a] -> Maybe a -> Int -> [a]
        replace [] _ _ = []
        replace (_:xs) (Just val) 0 = val:xs
        replace (_:xs) Nothing 0 = xs
        replace (x:xs) val i = x : (replace xs val $ i - 1)

        unwrapPair :: Monad m => (a, m b) -> m (a, b)
        unwrapPair (a, mb) = do b <- mb
                                return (a, b)
```

Comment: Can you include the definition for `buildQuotas`?  Or preferably you could reduce your code to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, `allocatePizzasImpl` doesn't typecheck (trying to match `(flavor, _)` pattern with type `Int`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your function `replace` is broken:

```
replace (_:xs) (Just val) 0 = val:xs
```

This doesn't pay any attention to the value it's replacing.  Wasn't your intention to replace just the pair corresponding to `key`?

I think you want

```
updateWith [] e k = []
updateWith ((k', v):kvs) e k
    | k' == k = case e v of
        Just v' -> (k, v'):kvs
        Nothing -> kvs
    | otherwise = (k', v) : updateWith kvs e k
```

Comment: This is a much nicer implementation than mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue (ignoring other conceptual things mentioned by the commenters) turned out to be using `fst` to extract the result from the State would for some reason not cause the State to actually be computed. Running the result through `seq` fixed it.

I'd be interested in knowing *why* this is the case, though!

**Edit**: As Daniel Wagner pointed out in the comments, I wasn't actually using inventory, which turned out to be the real bug. Marking this as accepted.

Comment: Just standard laziness. Why compute the resulting state if nobody cares what it is? (Note that you don't actually use `inventory` to make any decisions except what the next inventory should be!)

Comment: Fantastic point. Not using inventory is the real bug. Cheers!